# Two different mail servers for single domain

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have one domain, mydomain.com, whose emails are hosted on Google apps mail server. But i want to use the same domain name and host another LOCAL Postfix mail server with that same somain name, and send mails from that new server as well. is it possible?

May be i might have to add another MX record for this mail server? or add another SPF record?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MX is to tell other mail servers how your domain will receive mail.  If you're not doing that with your local Postfix, then you don't need to do anything with an MX record.  (Organizations can have multiple MX records, but that's more for redundancy.  I believe Google will have multiple MX records for your Apps account, for example).

You should have another SPF record, to tell anti-spam filters that your local Postfix is a designated sender for your domain.  You may want to do more than just an SPF record, depending on the "quality" of your IP address, i.e., if it's in some dynamic pool blacklist, you will have problems with anti-spam filters.

Note that your local Postfix can send mail regardless.  Having the right SPF record, etc., is to address anti-spam filters.

Comment: Yes, spam can be controlled by SPF, thanks for clarification. but i am getting a weird message in postfix " status=bounced (unknown user: "frank") , my email is frank@mydomain.com. whats causing it?

Comment: You probably need to configure Postfix so that it won't try any local delivery, i.e., it's trying to deliver to a local mail account "frank".  I don't recall the configuration name off hand, something like "Smart Host".  Or, search for Postfix configuration recipes for situations where you want no local delivery, or no local mailboxes.